# jQuery loader image inside button only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried this code where, for example, a submit button is shown in a login form. When the user clicks on that button, the text is changed to say "processing" and a loader icon is shown as well.

Here is the bootstrap button code:

```
<button id="loginbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();

        /*Change button text and show loading icon*/
        $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
            var img_route = "{{assetsUrl}}img/ajax-loader2.gif";
            $('#loginbtn').attr("disabled", true).html('<img src="'+img_route+'" style="float:left;margin-right:0.5em;" height="21" width="21"> Logging in ...');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        });
    });
```

This works fine on Chrome. However, if I click on that button when using either Firefox or Safari, the text is changed but the loading icon is not shown. Why is this happening? How can I make it work in both Safari and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihiruj/9hm0dk0f/1/) and it works, even in firefox. Is there more code you can provide ? and the real url you are using for the image.

moreover, i changed the image link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();

  /*Change button text and show loading icon*/
  $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    var img_route = "http://www.tutorialbunch.com/photoshop/animation/images/google-loading-icon11.gif";
    $('#loginbtn').attr("disabled", true).html('<img src="' + img_route + '" style="float:left;margin-right:0.5em;" height="21" width="21"> Logging in ...');
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```